# when i run my app in flutter android studio :

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[when i run my app this is what i get click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BETWH.png)

Comment: Try `flutter clean`.

Answer (score 0):

If the app crashes at startup, there should be an error message printed in the LogCat tab.